# How to differentiate alien voices apart?

Tags: aliens, communication

One day Earth is visited by a >4th dimensional alien entities, they do not have a physical body and all we know is that they can cause the air around a person to vibrate at different pitches seeming imitates voices, not to be mistaken for telepathy.

They are mimicking your own voice when communicating with you and you only, each individual is capable of talking to multiple persons any where in the world simultaneously (latency applies due to speed of causality).

Only a fraction of them (alien entities) managed to control their telekinetic power so that the air won't fatally scald a person they are talking to, think of Superman hypnotizing himself with "mental block" as he believes he is living in a world of cardboard.

Because of the great difficulty in controlling their ability they usually reuse sentences that you have said and limits communication to within 30 minutes fortnightly.

How can any human knows that it is indeed the encounter of the "<3rd" kind and not some mental illness or "mass hallucination?

Comment: Could you rephrase / elaborate on the Superman analogy, it doesn't really seem to fit the context or it's hard to understand how it does with the current wording

Comment: The differentiating alien voices apart question and the "How do you know you aren't hallucinating?" question seem to be different, could you edit it to just pick one?

Comment: @Zxyrra: my question is how to tell if it is the alien who is actually trying to communicate with you and not hearing voices.

Comment: It might be more clear to answerers if you call the question "How to different alien voices apart from hallucinations"

Comment: What does the body of this question have to do with the title?

Comment: @user6760 can you record these voices? if not, why?

Comment: @enkryptor: yes when the alien cause the immediate surrounding air around your head to vibrate then it can be picked up on mic.

Comment: @user6760 so what's the problem then? AFAIK you cannot record hallucinations, when people just "hear things"

Comment: @enkryptor: the meeting with the alien is not premeditated and they can simply talk to anyone.

Comment: Well, a voice from nowhere (regardless of its actual source) definitely could be mistaken as a hallucination by a random person. But the question wasn't about it, was it? Could you elaborate the question a little bit more, describe the situation for example?

Answer (score 2):

Your concept is a bit confusing. Why would you need to differentiate between voices if they all copy your voice? I suppose that's exactly your problem, distinguishing between different aliens that all sound the same. In terms of confirming you aren't hallucinating, resonance is my first thought, since they communicate with vibrations. There are other properties of waves that can be exploited but resonance would theoretically be a very tangible way to confirm 4D alien speak. A low-tech solution is a glass of water. Perhaps different "voices" make glasses filled with a different amounts of water resonate, or create unique sine wave patterns? Anyway you might be overcomplicating things. On one hand your description of different aliens talking to you with your voice sounds like it would be best represented as the relationship between a single character and several aliens.On the other hand your description of talking to multiple people anywhere in the world at the same time sounds like it would be best characterized by the relationship between a single alien and several characters. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

Your title and your question seem to be asking two different things ('distinguish two alien voices' vs 'distinguish aliens from hallucination'); since the latter has more detail, I'll focus my answer there.

The easiest way to distinguish a hallucination from reality is looking at its effect on other things. Since these aliens are causing the air to vibrate, the sound is "real" for all intents and purposes. This means that a phone or voice recorder would hear them just as well as you would.

If I thought I were hallucinating, the first thing I'd do would be to grab my cell phone and turn on the camera. Hallucinations generally aren't constant long-term things, so I wouldn't expect to hear them again when playing back a recording. And the fact that the recorded voice could show up in a spectrogram, or be perceived by other (perfectly sane) people, should be conclusive evidence.

This system isn't foolproof, though. For one, good luck convincing other people. The aliens are using your own voice, and don't appear in the video; "you recorded another audio track and overlaid it" is a more likely explanation for the weird recording.

In addition, if the aliens have enough precision to "draw" sound waves with ripples, they could also position the origin of those waves precisely inside your ear canal. If they did this, you would hear everything with perfect clarity, while other people (and your microphone) would hear nothing at all. This one is much harder to explain, since it's unlikely that someone would react to possible hallucinations by shoving a microphone in their ear just in case it's actually fourth-dimensional aliens creating actual sound waves inside their head.

Comment: Sorry my English is broken but ignore the title I know it is difficult to answer my original question so I change to differentiate between human and alien instead.